# Trigger creation on a table for inserting value in a column

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

How to create trigger to insert a value in a column depending on the combination of 3 other columns of same table of a newly inserted row in the table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EXECUTION_TRIGGER 

AFTER INSERT ON JOBS  
DECLARE 
V_A varchar2(100);
V_B varchar2(100);
V_C VARCHAR2(120);

BEGIN

select CATEGORY, METHOD,TECH  into V_A, V_B, V_C FROM JOBS

IF  V_C = '10X' AND V_B = '20X' AND V_A = '30X'

THEN

UPDATE JOBS 
SET EXECUTION = 1;

ELSE 

UPDATE JOBS 
SET EXECUTION = 2;


END IF ;
  NULL;
END
```

;

i am not able to execute this...

Comment: What have you tried yourself? 
Do you have some code already? 

If you want to know more about Triggers, have a look here: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/ They also have good example how Triggers work.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking, but if you're on 11g, perhaps you want to investigate [virtual columns](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1)?

Comment: You should edit the question and put the code there, so that it can be formatted correctly to make it easier to read!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `BEFORE INSERT` trigger here:

```
create or replace TRIGGER EXECUTION_TRIGGER before INSERT ON JOBS  
for each row
BEGIN
  if :new.CATEGORY = '30X' and :new.METHOD = '20X' and :new.TECH = '10X' then
    :new.execution := 1; 
  else
    :new.execution := 2; 
  end if;
END;
```

Test:

```
create table jobs (CATEGORY varchar2(10), METHOD    varchar2(10), 
                  TECH      varchar2(10), execution number(5));

insert into jobs (CATEGORY, METHOD, TECH) values ('30X', '20X', '10X');
insert into jobs (CATEGORY, METHOD, TECH) values ('abc', 'def', 'ghi');

select * from jobs;

CATEGORY   METHOD     TECH        EXECUTION
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
30X        20X        10X                 1 
abc        def        ghi                 2
```